# Default controller tests crash with redirect 302 instead status 200

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I created a new controller and phoenix automaticaly made some tests for it.

test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs

But when I run them all of them crash with a redirect error, this is an example:

```
  1) test shows chosen resource (Rumbl.VideoControllerTest)
     test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:29
     ** (RuntimeError) expected response with status 200, got: 302, with body:
     <html><body>You are being <a href="/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
     code: assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Show video"
     stacktrace:
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:362: Phoenix.ConnTest.response/2
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:376: Phoenix.ConnTest.html_response/2
       test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:32: (test)

warning: `Ecto.Changeset.cast/4` is deprecated, please use `cast/3` + `validate_required/3` instead
    (rumbl) web/models/video.ex:19: Rumbl.Video.changeset/2
    test/models/video_test.exs:10: Rumbl.VideoTest."test changeset with valid attributes"/1
    (ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/runner.ex:292: ExUnit.Runner.exec_test/1
    (stdlib) timer.erl:166: :timer.tc/1
    (ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/runner.ex:240: anonymous fn/3 in ExUnit.Runner.spawn_test/3

warning: `Ecto.Changeset.cast/4` is deprecated, please use `cast/3` + `validate_required/3` instead
    (rumbl) web/models/video.ex:19: Rumbl.Video.changeset/2
    test/models/video_test.exs:15: Rumbl.VideoTest."test changeset with invalid attributes"/1
    (ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/runner.ex:292: ExUnit.Runner.exec_test/1
    (stdlib) timer.erl:166: :timer.tc/1
    (ex_unit) lib/ex_unit/runner.ex:240: anonymous fn/3 in ExUnit.Runner.spawn_test/3



  2) test updates chosen resource and redirects when data is valid (Rumbl.VideoControllerTest)
     test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:47
     Assertion with == failed
     code:  assert redirected_to(conn) == video_path(conn, :show, video)
     left:  "/"
     right: "/manage/videos/12"
     stacktrace:
       test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:50: (test)



  3) test lists all entries on index (Rumbl.VideoControllerTest)
     test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:8
     ** (RuntimeError) expected response with status 200, got: 302, with body:
     <html><body>You are being <a href="/">redirected</a>.</body></html>
     code: assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Listing videos"
     stacktrace:
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:362: Phoenix.ConnTest.response/2
       (phoenix) lib/phoenix/test/conn_test.ex:376: Phoenix.ConnTest.html_response/2
       test/controllers/video_controller_test.exs:10: (test)
```

Here is some code of these tests:

```
  test "lists all entries on index", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = get conn, video_path(conn, :index)
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "Listing videos"
  end

  test "renders form for new resources", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = get conn, video_path(conn, :new)
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "New video"
  end

  test "creates resource and redirects when data is valid", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = post conn, video_path(conn, :create), video: @valid_attrs
    assert redirected_to(conn) == video_path(conn, :index)
    assert Repo.get_by(Video, @valid_attrs)
  end

  test "does not create resource and renders errors when data is invalid", %{conn: conn} do
    conn = post conn, video_path(conn, :create), video: @invalid_attrs
    assert html_response(conn, 200) =~ "New video"
  end
```

And here is some code of the controller:

```
  def action(conn, _) do
    apply(__MODULE__, action_name(conn),
          [conn, conn.params, conn.assigns.current_user])
  end

  def index(conn, _params, user) do
    videos = Repo.all(user_videos(user)) |> Repo.preload(:category)
    render(conn, "index.html", videos: videos)
  end

  def new(conn, _params, user) do
    changeset =
      user
      |> build_assoc(:videos)
      |> Video.changeset()

    render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
  end

  def create(conn, %{"video" => video_params}, user) do
    changeset =
      user
      |> build_assoc(:videos)
      |> Video.changeset(video_params)

    case Repo.insert(changeset) do
      {:ok, _video} ->
        conn
        |> put_flash(:info, "Video created successfully.")
        |> redirect(to: video_path(conn, :index))
      {:error, changeset} ->
        render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
    end
  end
```

I must me missing something obvious but cant make the tests work

Comment: Default Phoenix controller tests are not contain any kind of auth, you have to setup them yourself.

Comment: From the error message it looks like you need to provide some authentication credentials, otherwise you're being redirected away from the page you're trying to visit (just a sneaky suspicion)...